# I want to disable key for X seconds

Tags: c#-5.0

I am doing game where you are trying to avoid obstacles. And I made a key for slow motion. When player presses it,  it stays active for 3 seconds and after than I want to disable the key for 6 seconds to prevent him from pressing it again and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You know how to make a game go slomotion but can't disable a button... You started your project by asking this question I get the feeling...

Comment: Please provide more context - we have no clue what kind of UI you're building, which makes it very, very hard to help you...

Comment: It does not make sense to disable a key.  It makes sense to ignore a key press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
public static void Main()
{
    myButton.Enabled = false;
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    timer.Interval = 5000; // Specify the timespan
    timer.Enabled = true;         
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     myButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

You can add certain handlers to the `Elapsed` event and specify some time span (in millisecnonds) after which each handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer for this:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
t.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
t.Interval=3000;
t.Enabled=true;
aButton.Enabled = false;

 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     aButton.Enabled = true;
     (source as Timer).Enabled = false;
 }
```